# How do I invalidate @cached_property in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am currently using `@cached_property` on a model class and I would like to delete it on save so that it can be repopulated on the next call. How do I do this?
Example:

```
class Amodel():
    #...model_fields....

    @cached_property
    def db_connection(self):
        #get some thing in the db and cache here


instance = Amodel.objects.get(id=1)
variable = instance.db_connection

Amodel.objects.select_for_update().filter(id=1).update(#some variable)
#invalidate instance.db_connection
#new_variable = instance.db_connection
```

Thanks

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Just del it as documentation [says](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/utils/#django.utils.functional.cached_property). It will lead to recalculation on next access.

```
class SomeClass(object):
    
    @cached_property
    def expensive_property(self):
         return datetime.now()

obj = SomeClass()
print obj.expensive_property
print obj.expensive_property # outputs the same value as before
del obj.expensive_property
print obj.expensive_property # outputs new value
```

For Python 3 it's the same use of `del`. Below is an example of a try/except block.

```
try:
    del obj.expensive_property 
except AttributeError:
    pass
```

Comment: note this will generate an AttributeError if the property has not been accessed/cached. In that case wrap it with a try,except AttributeError.

Comment: Good info @dalore; terrible boilerplate on the part of the django devs :(

Comment: Note that if you are invalidating from within the class, you would use `del self.__dict__['expensive_property']`...unless there's a non-dunder way that I'm unaware of.

Comment: `@cached_property` is most definitely *not* a bit of terrible boilerplate! It's a concise use of the interplay between instance dictionaries and the descriptor protocol. It makes perfect sense that if you try and `delattr` before the property has been called/cached then it will throw `AttributeError`, that's bog-standard python behaviour. And it makes perfect sense because `cached_property` precisely *writes* the attribute to the instance dict in lieu of calling itself after the first time it is run. Take the time to look into it and you'll see that it's a sweet and economical nugget of code.

Comment: Link changed to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/utils/#django.utils.functional.cached_property; can't edit.

Comment: @jhrr No problem with `cached_property`.  It's the error-pattern that's suspect in this case, but as you say it's probably just done to reduce code because that's how python works.  In the case of a cached property it doesn't really make sense though, as the property that's being `del`'d  from a user perspective *does* exist.  It's a leaky abstraction.

Comment: Though it'd be a fair point to say that the use of `del` itself is the design problem there.

Answer (score 19):

I created a Django model mixin that invalidates all `@cached_property` properties on the model when `model.refresh_from_db()` is called. You can also manually invalidate the cached properties with `model.invalidate_cached_properties()`.

```
from django.utils.functional import cached_property


class InvalidateCachedPropertiesMixin():

    def refresh_from_db(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.invalidate_cached_properties()
        return super().refresh_from_db(*args, **kwargs)
            
    def invalidate_cached_properties(self):
        for key, value in self.__class__.__dict__.items():
            if isinstance(value, cached_property):
                self.__dict__.pop(key, None)
```

https://gitlab.com/snippets/1747035

Inspired by [Thomas Baden](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41938579/1248175)'s answer.

Comment: If you using `from functools import cached_property` it will not work. So I suggest, check multiple field types: `if isinstance(value, (cached_property, django_cached_property)):`

Comment: In case anyone else runs into this - this won't clear properties defined on a superclass. To do that you have to loop through every class in `self.__class__.__mro__` at the beginning of `invalidate_cached_properties`. Have also left a comment with the complete code on the gitlab link.

Answer (score 8):

Edited heavily due to ongoing development...  Now supports multiple tags for a given cached_property.

I encountered a similar issue, wherein I had a set of related `cached_property` objects which all needed simultaneous invalidation.  I solved it in this manner:

1. Extend `cached_property` to accept tag values and include a decorator classmethod:

   ```
   def __init__(self, func, *tags):
       self.func = func
       self.tags = frozenset(tags)

   @classmethod
   def tag(cls *tags):
       return lambda f: cls(f, *tags)
   ```
2. In my other objects, use my new `cached_property.tag` decorator classmethod to define tagged `cached_property` methods:

   ```
   @cached_property.tag("foo_group")
   def foo(self):
       return "foo"
   ```
3. On my object that makes use of the new decorator, write a method to invalidate all `cached_property` values with the named tag by walking the `__dict__` of the instantiated object's class.  This prevents accidental invocation of all `cached_property` methods:

   ```
   def invalidate(self, tag):
       for key, value in self.__class__.__dict__.items():
           if isinstance(value, cached_property) and tag in value.tags:
               self.__dict__.pop(key, None)
   ```

Now, to invalidate, I merely invoke `myobject.invalidate("foo_group")`.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to use `try` and `except`, and also write fewer lines, you can use:

```
if ("expensive_property" in obj.__dict__):
    del obj.expensive_property
```

Or:

```
if ("expensive_property" in obj.__dict__):
    delattr(obj, "expensive_property")
```

It will delete the cached property and it will be calculated again the next time it's accessed.

**Update**: Don't use `if (hasattr(obj, "expensive_property")):`! It will calculate the property if it's not cached already and will always return `True`!